# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Ajax.BeginForm is redirecting to a Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

In ASP.Net MVC 3.0 i am using a Ajax.Beginform

and hitting a JsonResult
on success of the form i am calling a jQuery Function.
but for some reason my form is redirecting to JsonAction

**my View**

---

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions
           {
               HttpMethod = "POST",
               OnSuccess = "ShowResult"
           }, new { id = "myform" }))
{
    // All form Fields
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="button standard" />
}
```

**My controller**

---

```
public JsonResult ActionName(FormCollection collection)
{
    return Json(new { _status },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**jQuery**

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowResult(data) {
   // alert("I am at ShowResult");
    if (data.isRedirect) {
        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
    }
}
```

for some reason, when i click submit.
it runs the JSonResult and redirects the page to host/controller/actionname
I have included my

```
<script src="@Url.Content("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

in my layout.cshtml

can any one tell me what could be wrong?

I found the problem. Now i have to find the solution
on submit
I am validating my form

```
$("#myform").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
   // my logic goes here....
 }});
```

If i exclude the validation Ajax form works as expected.
But if i validate my form then ajax form is not working as expected
Thanks

Comment: Is your javascript callback called? Have you checked with fiddler, that your JSon object is returned correctly to the browser? What  do you mean excactly with *redirecting to JsonAction*?

Comment: my java script is in the same page. Because it is redirecting to different page. JavaScript can;t be called. and yes my Json object is returned as expected. i see json result in the new redirected page

Answer (score 18, accepted):

when this happens its almost always because your script files aren't loaded

note from:

http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/unobstrusive-javascript-in-mvc-3-helps.html

1. Set the mentioned flag in the web.config:

   2. Include a reference to the jQuery library ~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js
   3. Include a reference to the library that hooks this magic at ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

So  load up fiddler http://fiddler2.com and see if the scripts are being called and loaded.

Comment: I see the problem all my script are correctly pointing. Problem is with id tag if i give html id tag to the form then this is not working. if i take of the ID then Ajax form works as expected. But i need my ID tag for Ajax form as i am validating it with it.