# Ajax.BeginForm does not work asynchronous

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax.BeginFrom in Index view to test the method in Home controller

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: "TestMethod",
        controllerName: "Home",
        ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "TestInfo",
            LoadingElementId = "Progress"
        }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <div id="TestInfo"></div>
}
```

And

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult TestMethod()
{
    return Content("ok");
}
```

But after submit, the Page redirect to /Home/TestMethod and show 'ok' .

I've added

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in webconfig and

```
<script src="@Links.Scripts.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_min_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in my layout. But it still does not work asynchronous.
Where is the problem?

Comment: See below post :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273819/asp-net-mvc-3-0-ajax-beginform-is-redirecting-to-a-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when this happens its almost always because your script files aren't loaded, see below post :

http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/unobstrusive-javascript-in-mvc-3-helps.html

Set the mentioned flag in the web.config:

1. Include a reference to the jQuery library ~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js
2. Include a reference to the library that hooks this magic at ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: You cannot use Ajax.BeginForm for async file upload, but there is workeround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972470/c-sharp-mvc3-ajax-beginform-to-upload-file-not-working