# Modal form refreshing to main page while returning validation instead of displaying in Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

**Situation**

I am working on an application where I have a table of three fields, I add items to that table by clicking a button and loading a modal pop up where I add the values.

**Problem**

I have validation in my controller. If for any reason validation fails I want to display the error back on the form. **The problem is**, when I submit and the validation error occurs, the form goes to my edit view and also redirects the browser to the page. So instead of my link "`http://localhost:1979/Crops/Edit/34`" remaining as a modal, the browser actually redirects to it and my css/bootstrap/modal is lost.

**What I have tried**

1) I have attempted to use ajax so that my page would not refresh or redirect so  I have

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Crops", null,  new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
```

2) I have added the jquery validate to my script as below

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

3) I verified that it is also in my web config.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Despite this, when clicking submit, my page still takes me to the edit page where it displays the validation.
Grateful if I could get assistance so when I submit it shows the validation right there in the modal form instead of going to the edit page.

I have added the edit page along with the index page which calls the model below

**Edit Page**

```
@model PSLicense_app.Models.HOLD_cropsGrown

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Crop Grown</h4>
</div>
<h2> </h2>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Crops", null,  new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@*@using (Html.BeginForm())
{*@
    <div class="modal-body">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.availSell)
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4></h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Holding_ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
           --Fields here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Edit" />
    </div>
}
```

Index (Edit button calls above Modal Code)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <h2></h2>
    <!-- modal placeholder-->
    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class=" modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id='myModalContent'  ></div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
@using GridMvc.Html


    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">

        </div>



        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Numof)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.availSell)
                </th> 

            </tr>


            @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Numof)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.availSell)
        </td>

<th>


        @Html.NoEncodeActionLink("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>", "Edit", "Edit", "Crops", routeValues: new { id = item.id }, htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "", @class = "btn btn-default modal-link" })


</th>


    </tr>
}

        </table>

    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading Please Wait test" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            // Initialize modal dialog
            // attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
            // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
            $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
                $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
            });
            //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
            $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
                $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").replaceWith('<div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body"><div style="text-align:center"><img src="/../Content/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading Please Wait" /></div></div></div>');

            });
            //Diable diabledtabs
            $('ul.nav> li.disabled > a').click(function () { return false; });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` for the `Ajax.BeginForm()` method to work (otherwise it makes a normal submit)

Comment: @StephenMuecke But isnt that what is in my <head>?

Comment: No (all you have is `jquery`, `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Mistook them, I believe it works now, Validation error does not show but at least the form isnt submitted again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Ajax.BeginForm is redirecting to a Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273819/asp-net-mvc-3-0-ajax-beginform-is-redirecting-to-a-page)